# Why i got an Error by using a Class in Swift Playgrounds

Tags: swift

I tryed to use a class with the type Timer to repeat a while clause with a delay in swift Playgrounds but i got the error:

> Declaration is expected!

What can i do?

```
class LedAnimation: Timer { 

    while ledAnimationVarible < 16 {
    allCircles[ledAnimationVarible].color = .blue
        ledAnimationVarible += 1
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a valid class. Your code within the class should be defined within a function

```
class LedAnimation: Timer { 

    func animateLed(ledAnimationVarible: Int) {
        while ledAnimationVarible < 16 {
            allCircles[ledAnimationVarible].color = .blue
            ledAnimationVarible += 1
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Just one additional Question: How can I get a delay in the loop? In XCode i would use sleep() but that function doesn’t work in swift Playgrounds.

Comment: For animation... you can use `Animate(withDuration)` and you can use delay or completions to nest animations or you can sue key frames to start different animations at different times

Comment: @Admiral_kirk02 don't use `sleep`, since that is synchronously blocking the main thread as well, so the UI will become unresponsive. Use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5, execute: { print("1.5 seconds later") })`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you cannot just write executable code outside functions. You need to enclose your `while` loop in a function.

```
class LedAnimation {
   func animateLeds(){
       while ledAnimationVarible < 16 {
           allCircles[ledAnimationVarible].color = .blue
           ledAnimationVarible += 1
       }
   }
}
```

However, you also shouldn't subclass `Timer` as the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer) clearly states.

Answer (score 1):

You receive the following error because `while` statement cannot be located in class body.

Wrap it to a `function`

```
class LedAnimation: Timer {

    func foo() {
        while ledAnimationVarible < 16 {
            allCircles[ledAnimationVarible].color = .blue
            ledAnimationVarible += 1
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your executable statements are not placed inside any executable scope. You need a function to wrap your executable statements.

```
class LedAnimation: Timer {

    func doSomething()
    {
        while ledAnimationVarible < 16 {
            allCircles[ledAnimationVarible].color = .blue
            ledAnimationVarible += 1
        }
    }
}
```